# terraform apply could not find the resource helm_release

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I am trying to setup helm and helm releases through terraform, as per `terraform plan`

```
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # helm_release.prometheus_vsi will be created
  + resource "helm_release" "prometheus_vsi" {
      + chart            = "stable/prometheus"
      + disable_webhooks = false
      + force_update     = false
      + id               = (known after apply)
      + metadata         = (known after apply)
      + name             = "prometheus-vsi"
      + namespace        = "prometheus"
      + recreate_pods    = false
      + repository       = "stable"
      + reuse            = false
      + reuse_values     = false
      + status           = "DEPLOYED"
      + timeout          = 300
      + values           = [
          + <<~EOT
                rbac:
                  create: true
                   enabled: false
            EOT,
        ]
      + verify           = false
      + version          = "10.2.0"
      + wait             = true
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

but when I run `terraform apply` its throw error mentioned in "Panic Output".

#### Terraform Version

Terraform v0.12.18
+ provider.aws v2.43.0
+ provider.helm v0.10.4
+ provider.kubernetes v1.10.0
+ provider.local v1.4.0
+ provider.null v2.1.2
+ provider.random v2.2.1
+ provider.template v2.1.2

Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version
is 0.12.19. You can update by downloading from https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html

#### Affected Resource(s)

- helm_release

#### Terraform Configuration Files

```
provider "helm" {
  version         = "~> 0.10"
  install_tiller  = true
  service_account = local.helm_service_account_name
  debug           = true
  kubernetes {
    config_path = "${path.module}/kubeconfig_${module.eks.kubeconfig}"
  }
}
data "helm_repository" "stable" {
  name = "stable"
  url  = "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com"
}

resource "helm_release" "prometheus_vsi" {
  name       = "prometheus-vsi"
  repository = data.helm_repository.stable.metadata[0].name
  chart      = "stable/prometheus"
  namespace  = local.prometheus_ns
  version    = "10.2.0"
  values = [
    "${file("${local.chart_root}/prometheus/prometheus-values.yaml")}"
  ]
}
```

#### Debug Output

I have enable the `debug=true` but its not producing helm particular logs

#### Panic Output

```
Error: error installing: the server could not find the requested resource (post deployments.apps)

  on main.tf line 205, in resource "helm_release" "prometheus_vsi":
 205: resource "helm_release" "prometheus_vsi" {
```

#### Expected Behavior

As per `terraform plan` it should create `helm_release` in kubernetes.

#### Actual Behavior

Terraform apply throwing error.

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. `terraform apply`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Stable repo is deprecated and all the charts were removed on November 2020.

Try the chart: prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack

URL: https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts